# when and why would a class be a subclass of NSObject?

Tags: swift

In some tutorials, I've seen:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    var a: String!
    var b: String!

    init(a: String, b: String) {
        super.init()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that swift classes didn't need to subclass anything.  Is there any reason why someone would want to subclass from NSObject ?

Answer (score 2):

`NSObject` class is not so important. What really is important is the `NSObject` protocol, in Swift named `NSObjectProtocol`.

For example, most protocols in Cocoa/CocoaTouch inherit from `NSObjectProtocol`. That means that if you want to use such protocols (for example, to implement delegates), you have to implement all the methods from `NSObjectProtocol`. That's pretty hard but `NSObject` class implements them all for you so the easiest solution is to inherit from `NSObject` class.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't subclass NSObject you lose all the cool stuff Selector that comes with it: performSelector, respondsToSelector etc...
Also - this way you can make sure your Swift code objects can interact with legacy Objective-C code.